# how to subtract line by line from two different files

Tags: bash, awk, sh

I have two files as below:

```
 file1 (10 lines) :
 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 2 3 4 5 1 1
 ...... 
 file2 (4 lines ) :
 1 2 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 
 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 3 1
 .......
```

I want to take difference for each row in file1 between file2 and file1 and save it to different file3$i. which may look like:
for 1st row of file1

```
 file31 (4 lines) :
 0 2 2 1 0 0 0 0 0
 0 2 0 1 0 0 0 2 0
 ..........
```

To be more clear.
For the 1st row of file1 the output is like:

```
 1st row of file2 - 1st row of file1
 2nd row of file2 - 1st row of file1
 3rd row of file2 - 1st row of file1
 4th row of file2 - 1st row of file1
```

For the 2nd row of file1 the output is like:

```
 1st row of file2 - 2nd row of file1
 2nd row of file2 - 2nd row of file1
 3rd row of file2 - 2nd row of file1
 4th row of file2 - 2nd row of file1
```

and so on for the rest of the rows in file1.

I tried using awk but could not find a smart solution.

Comment: in this example there will be 10 output files for each row of file1. So in the example I have just printed the first  one i.e. file2 - 1st row of file1

Comment: I have modified the possible output and hope its clear now. Basically I want to subtract each entry of a row in file1 from corresponding entries in each row in file2

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `awk` command:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {
   for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)
      a[FNR,i]=$i
   nr1=FNR
   next
} {
   out="outfile" FNR
   for(r=1; r<=nr1; r++) {
      for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
         v = a[r,i] - $i
         printf "%s%s", (v>0?v:0), (i==NF)?ORS:OFS > out
      }
   }
   close(out)
}' file2 file1
```

This command will output a separate output file for each row in `file1`, with names as `outfile1`, `outfile2`, `outfile3` etc.

**Output:**

```
cat outfile1
0 2 2 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 2 0 1 0 0 0 2 0

cat outfile2
0 1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 2 0
```

Comment: This is not working!! The 2nd row does not meet the answer.